# Asymmetric table

Tags: tables

I have a question regarding my table. It appears that the code delivers a table that devotes the majority of the space to last column. I couldn't figure out the reason. What might be the problem?

```
\documentclass{buthesis}
\usepackage[usenames]{color} %used for font color
\usepackage{amssymb} %maths
\usepackage{amsmath} %maths
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %useful to type directly diacritic characters
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{adjustbox, lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}
\usepackage{color}   %May be necessary if you want to color links
\usepackage{color}   %May be necessary if you want to color links
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{ colorlinks=false, linktoc=all, hidelinks }
\usepackage{booktabs}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\usepackage{pstool}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\BBAA}{ve}}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\BOthers}[1]{vd.}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{url}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck = false, justification=justified}
\caption{Seçilmiş gelişmiş ülkeler için iş çevrimleri istatistikleri}   


\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}

\begin{tabular}{cccccc}

\label{tab:buscycle2}


\textbf{İstatistik} & \textbf{İsviçre} & \textbf{Kanada} & \textbf{Danimarka} &  \textbf{Avustralya} & \textbf{Ortalama}  \\
\hline
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\textbf{Varyans}} \\
 $\sigma_{y}$  & 2 & 3 & 3 & 2 & 2.5\\
 ${\sigma_{c}}/{\sigma_{y}}$ & 0.5& 0.60 & 0.76 & 1.00 & 0.72  \\
 ${\sigma_{g}}/{\sigma_{y}}$ & 1.11 & 1.92 & 1.88 & 0.66 & 0.86 \\
 ${\sigma_{i}}/{\sigma_{y}}$ & 2.15 & 2.73 & 3.30 & 4.66  & 3.31\\
 ${\sigma_{x}}/{\sigma_{y}}$ & 2.61 & 3.05 & 1.75 & 3.18  & 2.94\\
 ${\sigma_{m}}/{\sigma_{y}}$ & 2.30 & 1.55 & 2.48 & 4.04 & 2.48 \\
 ${\sigma_{tb}}/{\sigma_{y}}$ & 0.62 & 0.75  & 0.44 & 1.13  & 0.83\\
 \hline
 \multicolumn{6}{l}{\textbf{Y ile korelasyon}} \\
 c  & 0.58 & 0.57 & 0.72 & 0.72 & 0.63 \\
 ${g}/{y}$  & -0.63 & -0.84 & -0.63 & -0.73 & -0.40 \\
 i  & 0.83 & 0.68 & 0.96 & 0.61 &  0.70\\
 x  & 0.75 & 0.55 & 0.66  & -0.08 &  0.39\\
 m  & 0.62& 0.66 & 0.73 & 0.46 & 0.23\\
 tby  &  0.50 & 0.32 & -0.40 & -0.20 &  0.12\\
  tb  & 0.56   & 0.37  & -0.26 & -0.17 & 0.18\\
 cay  & -0.21 & 0.74 & -0.68 & -0.51 & 0.13  \\
 \hline
  \multicolumn{6}{l}{\textbf{Otokorelasyon}} \\
 y & 0.67 & 0.80 & 0.73 & 0.78 &  0.78\\
 c & 0.70 & 0.88 & 0. 66 & 0.81 &  0.82\\
 g & 0.59 & 0.86 & 0.72&0.64 &  0.75\\
 i & 0.61& 0.81 & 0.78 & 0.81 &  0.79\\
 x & 0.44&0.87 &0.67  & 0.90 & 0.82 \\
 m & 0.49 & 0.46 & 0.71 & 0.72 & 0.57\\
 tby & 0.15 &0.94 &0.65 & 0.89 & 0.81 \\
  tb & 0.20 & 0.93 & 0.66 & 0.89 & 0.81  \\
 cay & 0.18 & 0.72 & 0.52 & 0.45 & 0.56\\
 \hline
    \multicolumn{6}{l}{\footnotesize Kaynak: Dünya Bankası verileri kullanılarak yazar tarafından oluşturulmuştur.  \url{https://databank.worldbank.org/source/world-development-indicators} } \\

\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is the `buthesis` document class available online?

Comment: The main cause of the table's "asymmetry", as you call it, is the presence of the  `\multicolumn{6}{l}{\footnotesize ...}` directive. Change it to `\multicolumn{6}{@{}p{10.5cm}}{\footnotesize\raggedright ...}`.

Comment: please make MWE clean, that is without things like `turkish`, `buthesis`, etc. Your question is about "Asymmetric table", right?
`

Comment: @BlackMild - Since the document appears to be in Turkish, including the material in the table footnote, I don't think it can be said that `\usepackage[turkish]{babel}` is unnecessary.

Comment: Hi mico I downloaded it from university's website.

Answer (score 5):

> It appears that the code delivers a table that devotes the majority of the space to last column. I couldn't figure out the reason.

The main reason for the "asymmetry" is the way you typeset the table footnote: The instruction

```
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\footnotesize ...}
```

does not allow line breaks in its argument.

I can think of two remedies:

- Replace the `l` column type, which does not allow automatic line-breaking, with the `p` column type (and a suitably chosen width):

  ```
  \multicolumn{6}{@{}p{10.3cm}}{\footnotesize\raggedright ...}
  ```

  I'd call this the brute-force way.
- Load the `threeparttable` environment, take the footnote material out of the `tabular` environment, and encase the caption statement, the `tabular` environment, and the footnote material in a `threeparttable` environment. With this setup,, the width of the footnote material is limited automatically to that of the `tabular` environment. That's the solution pursued in the code below.

Whatever else you end up doing, do allow for automatic alignment of the numbers in the five data columns on their respective decimal markers. One way to achieve this is to load the `siunitx` package and its `S` column type.

The following solution employs the `report` document class since I don't have access to the `buthesis` document class. It also employs the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package, it doesn't employ bold-facing of headers as I consider that to be both unnecessary and visually distracting, and I also got rid of unnecessary pairs of curly braces since they add nothing but code clutter. E.g., I replaced all instances of `{\sigma_{y}}` with `\sigma_{y}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[usenames]{color} %used for font color
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath} %maths
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
%\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{apacite} % for \BBAA and \BOthers macros
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\usepackage{pstool}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\BBAA}{ve}}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\BOthers}[1]{vd.}}

\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\usepackage{siunitx,threeparttable} % <-- new

\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{hyperref} % load this package LAST
\hypersetup{colorlinks=false, linktoc=all, hidelinks }

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht!]
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false, justification=justified}

\begin{threeparttable} % <-- new
\caption{Seçilmiş gelişmiş ülkeler için iş çevrimleri istatistikleri}   
\label{tab:buscycle2}

\begin{tabular}{@{} >{$}l<{$} *{5}{S[table-format=-1.2]} @{}}
% \toprule % (optional)
$İstatistik$ & {İsviçre} & {Kanada} & {Danimarka} &  {Avustralya} & {Ortalama}  \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{Varyans} \\
 \sigma_{y}  & 2 & 3 & 3 & 2 & 2.5\\
 \sigma_{c}/\sigma_{y}  & 0.50 & 0.60 & 0.76 & 1.00 & 0.72 \\
 \sigma_{g}/\sigma_{y}  & 1.11 & 1.92 & 1.88 & 0.66 & 0.86 \\
 \sigma_{i}/\sigma_{y}  & 2.15 & 2.73 & 3.30 & 4.66 & 3.31 \\
 \sigma_{x}/\sigma_{y}  & 2.61 & 3.05 & 1.75 & 3.18 & 2.94 \\
 \sigma_{m}/\sigma_{y}  & 2.30 & 1.55 & 2.48 & 4.04 & 2.48 \\
 \sigma_{tb}/\sigma_{y} & 0.62 & 0.75 & 0.44 & 1.13 & 0.83 \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{Y ile korelasyon} \\
 c   &  0.58 &  0.57 &  0.72 &  0.72 &  0.63 \\
 g/y & -0.63 & -0.84 & -0.63 & -0.73 & -0.40 \\
 i   &  0.83 &  0.68 &  0.96 &  0.61 &  0.70\\
 x   &  0.75 &  0.55 &  0.66 & -0.08 &  0.39\\
 m   &  0.62 &  0.66 &  0.73 &  0.46 &  0.23\\
 tby &  0.50 &  0.32 & -0.40 & -0.20 &  0.12\\
  tb &  0.56 &  0.37 & -0.26 & -0.17 &  0.18\\
 cay & -0.21 &  0.74 & -0.68 & -0.51 &  0.13\\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{{Otokorelasyon}} \\
 y   & 0.67 & 0.80 & 0.73 & 0.78 & 0.78\\
 c   & 0.70 & 0.88 & 0.66 & 0.81 & 0.82\\
 g   & 0.59 & 0.86 & 0.72 & 0.64 & 0.75\\
 i   & 0.61 & 0.81 & 0.78 & 0.81 & 0.79\\
 x   & 0.44 & 0.87 & 0.67 & 0.90 & 0.82\\
 m   & 0.49 & 0.46 & 0.71 & 0.72 & 0.57\\
 tby & 0.15 & 0.94 & 0.65 & 0.89 & 0.81\\
 tb  & 0.20 & 0.93 & 0.66 & 0.89 & 0.81\\
 cay & 0.18 & 0.72 & 0.52 & 0.45 & 0.56\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\smallskip\footnotesize\raggedright 
Kaynak: Dünya Bankası verileri kullanılarak yazar tarafından oluşturulmuştur.  
\url{https://databank.worldbank.org/source/world-development-indicators}

\end{threeparttable} % <-- new
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

  -

Answer (score 4):

As [Mico already explained](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/505522/134144), the reason for the too wide table is the `l` tpe column that you used in the last `\multicolumn` command. An `l` type column does not allow for linebreaks inside the cell. In the following example, I have replaced with a `p` type column. I have also used the horizontal lines from the `booktabs` package that you already load (twice). I have also used the `siunitx` package for an improved alignment of the numbers in the columns 2 to 5. I have also used `tabular*` in combination with `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` to make the table exactly as wide as the textwidth. In the `article` class that I had to use because I didn't have the document class from your question, the table is already almost as wide as the textwidth. Lastly, I have also replaced the `\begin{table}[H]` wfrom the `float` package with `\begin{center}
\captionsetup{type=table}` (uses the `caption` package that you already load).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{xcolor} %used for font color
\usepackage{amssymb} %maths
\usepackage{amsmath} %maths
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %useful to type directly diacritic characters
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\usepackage{pstool}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{ colorlinks=false, linktoc=all, hidelinks }


\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\captionsetup{type=table}
\caption{Seçilmiş gelişmiş ülkeler için iş çevrimleri istatistikleri}
\label{tab:buscycle2}   

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c*{5}{S[table-format=-1.2]}}

\textbf{İstatistik} & \textbf{İsviçre} & \textbf{Kanada} & \textbf{Danimarka} &  \textbf{Avustralya} & \textbf{Ortalama}  \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\textbf{Varyans}} \\
 $\sigma_{y}$  & 2 & 3 & 3 & 2 & 2.5\\
 ${\sigma_{c}}/{\sigma_{y}}$ & 0.5& 0.60 & 0.76 & 1.00 & 0.72  \\
 ${\sigma_{g}}/{\sigma_{y}}$ & 1.11 & 1.92 & 1.88 & 0.66 & 0.86 \\
 ${\sigma_{i}}/{\sigma_{y}}$ & 2.15 & 2.73 & 3.30 & 4.66  & 3.31\\
 ${\sigma_{x}}/{\sigma_{y}}$ & 2.61 & 3.05 & 1.75 & 3.18  & 2.94\\
 ${\sigma_{m}}/{\sigma_{y}}$ & 2.30 & 1.55 & 2.48 & 4.04 & 2.48 \\
 ${\sigma_{tb}}/{\sigma_{y}}$ & 0.62 & 0.75  & 0.44 & 1.13  & 0.83\\
 \midrule
 \multicolumn{6}{l}{\textbf{Y ile korelasyon}} \\
 c  & 0.58 & 0.57 & 0.72 & 0.72 & 0.63 \\
 ${g}/{y}$  & -0.63 & -0.84 & -0.63 & -0.73 & -0.40 \\
 i  & 0.83 & 0.68 & 0.96 & 0.61 &  0.70\\
 x  & 0.75 & 0.55 & 0.66  & -0.08 &  0.39\\
 m  & 0.62& 0.66 & 0.73 & 0.46 & 0.23\\
 tby  &  0.50 & 0.32 & -0.40 & -0.20 &  0.12\\
  tb  & 0.56   & 0.37  & -0.26 & -0.17 & 0.18\\
 cay  & -0.21 & 0.74 & -0.68 & -0.51 & 0.13  \\
 \midrule
  \multicolumn{6}{l}{\textbf{Otokorelasyon}} \\
 y & 0.67 & 0.80 & 0.73 & 0.78 &  0.78\\
 c & 0.70 & 0.88 & 0. 66 & 0.81 &  0.82\\
 g & 0.59 & 0.86 & 0.72&0.64 &  0.75\\
 i & 0.61& 0.81 & 0.78 & 0.81 &  0.79\\
 x & 0.44&0.87 &0.67  & 0.90 & 0.82 \\
 m & 0.49 & 0.46 & 0.71 & 0.72 & 0.57\\
 tby & 0.15 &0.94 &0.65 & 0.89 & 0.81 \\
  tb & 0.20 & 0.93 & 0.66 & 0.89 & 0.81  \\
 cay & 0.18 & 0.72 & 0.52 & 0.45 & 0.56\\
 \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{6}{p{\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}{\footnotesize Kaynak: Dünya Bankası verileri kullanılarak yazar tarafından oluşturulmuştur. \newline  \url{https://databank.worldbank.org/source/world-development-indicators} } \\

\end{tabular*}
\end{minipage} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. Just curious, though, about the following: Why did you replace the `table` envirohment with a `center` environment?

Comment: @Mico: I thought it might be better to not use `[H]` as a float posistion. I myself sometimes hasd problems with this approach. Instead one could use the `captionof` command. This however will interfere with the `hypcap` option from hyperref and issue a warning. This can be overcome by using `\captionsetup{type=table}
\caption{...}`.

Comment: The `center` environment was initially used to keep the tabular and the caption together and to add some vertical white space around it. After some texting I just came to realize that a `minipage` is better suited to keep tabular and caption together on the same page. I have edited my question to replace `center` with `minipage`.

Comment: Many thanks for these explanations.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help @leandriis

Comment: Thank you very much for the help @Mico

Answer (score 2):

You need no `adjustbox`, but `tabular*`. Also, the bottom note need not be in the tabular.

I reformatted your preamble to be more consistent. A couple of `\renewcommand` have been commented because they are about undefined commands with the preamble (of course, I don't have `buthesis`, so I used `book`).

I removed all boldface, that's not really needed.

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %useful to type directly diacritic characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}

\usepackage{amssymb} %maths
\usepackage{amsmath} %maths

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[usenames]{color} %used for font color
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{pstool}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{stackengine}
%\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}

\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}

\hypersetup{ colorlinks=false, linktoc=all, hidelinks }

%\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\BBAA}{ve}}
%\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\BOthers}[1]{vd.}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck = false, justification=justified}
\caption{Seçilmiş gelişmiş ülkeler için iş çevrimleri istatistikleri}   
\label{tab:buscycle2}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  c
  S[table-format=-1.2]
  S[table-format=-1.2]
  S[table-format=-1.2]
  S[table-format=-1.2]
  S[table-format=-1.2]
  @{}
}
\toprule
\textbf{İstatistik} &
{\textbf{İsviçre}} &
{\textbf{Kanada}} &
{\textbf{Danimarka}} &
{\textbf{Avustralya}} &
{\textbf{Ortalama}} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{@{}l@{}}{\textbf{Varyans}} \\
$\sigma_{y}$             & 2    & 3    & 3    & 2    & 2.5  \\
$\sigma_{c}/\sigma_{y}$  & 0.5  & 0.60 & 0.76 & 1.00 & 0.72 \\
$\sigma_{g}/\sigma_{y}$  & 1.11 & 1.92 & 1.88 & 0.66 & 0.86 \\
$\sigma_{i}/\sigma_{y}$  & 2.15 & 2.73 & 3.30 & 4.66 & 3.31 \\
$\sigma_{x}/\sigma_{y}$  & 2.61 & 3.05 & 1.75 & 3.18 & 2.94 \\
$\sigma_{m}/\sigma_{y}$  & 2.30 & 1.55 & 2.48 & 4.04 & 2.48 \\
$\sigma_{tb}/\sigma_{y}$ & 0.62 & 0.75 & 0.44 & 1.13 & 0.83 \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{@{}l@{}}{\textbf{Y ile korelasyon}} \\
c     &  0.58 &  0.57 &  0.72 &  0.72 &  0.63 \\
$g/y$ & -0.63 & -0.84 & -0.63 & -0.73 & -0.40 \\
i     &  0.83 &  0.68 &  0.96 &  0.61 &  0.70 \\
x     &  0.75 &  0.55 &  0.66 & -0.08 &  0.39 \\
m     &  0.62 &  0.66 &  0.73 &  0.46 &  0.23 \\
tby   &  0.50 &  0.32 & -0.40 & -0.20 &  0.12 \\
tb    &  0.56 &  0.37 & -0.26 & -0.17 &  0.18 \\
cay   & -0.21 &  0.74 & -0.68 & -0.51 &  0.13 \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{@{}l@{}}{\textbf{Otokorelasyon}} \\
y   & 0.67 & 0.80 & 0.73 & 0.78 & 0.78 \\
c   & 0.70 & 0.88 & 0.66 & 0.81 & 0.82 \\
g   & 0.59 & 0.86 & 0.72 & 0.64 & 0.75 \\
i   & 0.61 & 0.81 & 0.78 & 0.81 & 0.79 \\
x   & 0.44 & 0.87 & 0.67 & 0.90 & 0.82 \\
m   & 0.49 & 0.46 & 0.71 & 0.72 & 0.57 \\
tby & 0.15 & 0.94 & 0.65 & 0.89 & 0.81 \\
tb  & 0.20 & 0.93 & 0.66 & 0.89 & 0.81 \\
cay & 0.18 & 0.72 & 0.52 & 0.45 & 0.56 \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{6}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}{\footnotesize\raggedright
  Kaynak: Dünya Bankası verileri kullanılarak yazar tarafından oluşturulmuştur.
  \url{https://databank.worldbank.org/source/world-development-indicators}}
\end{tabular*}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

[image]